# Implicit declaration of function 'cond_resched' that is defined as macro in included header

Tags: c, linux-kernel, declaration, implicit

I'm trying to build a kernel with some patches that affect the same files and have a problem.
While building, i get an error:

> arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h: In function 'copy_from_user': arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h:81:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'cond_resched' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

At first i followed the code and found out that the pointed string is:

> if (access_ok(VERIFY_READ, from, n))

`access_ok(...)` is a macro from file uaccess.h, that does include `cond_resched()` call.
Actual `cond_resched()` call is defined in `linux/sched.h` and is #included into `uaccess.h` file. Also i tried to include it into `uaccess_64.h` file but it doesn't help. So i'm out of ideas how it could be implicitly declared.

Comment: You might have a circular header file dependency, or perhaps the needed file is conditionally excluded. Try `gcc -H <other flags>` to see which files are `#include`d where, and `gcc -E <other flags>` to see the file after preprocessing.

Comment: Can't really help without knowing what the patches are, but it sounds like the patches are either broken or for a different version of the kernel, or similar. (I've edited your tags to say "linux-kernel", as that's more appropriate).

Comment: Patches are PAX and RT linux for appropriate version of kernel (3.6.11)

Comment: I'm using `rpmbuild`, so i managed to add `-H` flag and found out that there is no sign of `linux/sched.h` before the error, and i currently cannot add `-E` flag (some `fixdep` executable cannot be executed because it is created default with `-rw` permission and i cannot change it at the moment).